# showing a span on hovering of a link using css

Tags: css

i have an link, when I hover it, I want a span to appear using CSS only.

HTML is here:

```
<a href="#" class="tooltip-trigger">Rules</a>

<span class="tooltip">
some personal information rules some personal information rules some personal information rules some personal information rules some personal information rules 
</span>
```

CSS is here:

```
.tooltip{ display: none;}
    .tooltip-trigger {
    background: url(../images/right-arro.png) right 13px no-repeat;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 33px;
    line-height: 33px;
    padding: 0 15px 0 6px;
    color: #2578E8;

    }
    .tooltip-trigger :hover > .tooltip{ display: block;}
```

fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/LBE55/

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

Firstly, `>` is the [child combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators) selector, not a sibling selector. Your `span` element isn't a child of your `a` element; it's a sibling. You'll want to use the [adjacent sibling combinator (`+`)](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators) instead.

Secondly, `:hover` needs to be directly after `.tooltip-trigger` (remove the space), otherwise you're calling the hover on an element contained within your `a` element (of which there are none):

```css
.tooltip-trigger:hover + .tooltip { display: block; }
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LBE55/3/).

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the span inside link tag

```
    <a href="#" class="tooltip-trigger">Rules<span class="tooltip">some personal information rules some personal information rules some personal information rules some personal information rules some personal information rules </span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you wrote the css, span has to be inside of a to appear
Try this I found on a tutorial:

```
.tooltip {
display: inline;
position: relative;
}
.tooltip:hover:after {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
border-radius: 5px;
bottom: 26px;
color: #FFFFFF;
content: attr(title);
left: 20%;
padding: 5px 15px;
position: absolute;
width: 220px;
z-index: 98;
}
.tooltip:hover:before {
-moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
-moz-border-left-colors: none;
-moz-border-right-colors: none;
-moz-border-top-colors: none;
border-color: #333333 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
border-image: none;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 6px 6px 0;
bottom: 20px;
content: "";
left: 50%;
position: absolute;
z-index: 99;
}
```

And the html:

```
<a class="tooltip" title="This is a tooltip" href="#"><span title="More">Tooltip Example</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// another way

.tooltip-trigger:hover ~  .tooltip { display: block; }
```